# Why am i getting parent is not defined when trying to add relation with parse.com node sdk

Tags: node.js, parse-platform, relation

I've already saved myreferenceobject and in the sucess function, I'm  attempting to run a loop and create a number of other objects save as "relations" to the refernced object.

```
                  // already have a reference to myreferenceobject

                  myobject.set("Name", artists_input["Name"]);
                  myobject.set("JbId", 12334);
                  myobject.save(null, {
                    success: function(myobject) {

                      console.log('New object created with objectId: ' + artist.id);
                      var relation = myreferenceobject.relation("Objects");
                      relation.add(myobject);
                      myreferenceobject.save();

                    },
                    error: function(myobject, error) {
                      // Execute any logic that should take place if the save fails.
                      // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
                      console.log('Failed to create new myobject, with error code: ' + error.message);
                    }
                  });
```

When I run the script I get the following error

```
ReferenceError: parent is not defined
 at ParseRelation.add 
/home/myapp/node_modules/parse/lib/node/ParseRelation.js:102
      return parent;
             ^
```

I followed the syntax provided by parse but I am still getting this error

Any idea?

Here is much simpler example that also fails

```
  var TestObject = Parse.Object.extend("TestObject");
  var testObject = new TestObject();
  testObject.set("Name", "testName");

  testObject.save(null, {
    success: function(testObject) {
      // Execute any logic that should take place after the object is saved.
      console.log('New testObject created with objectId: ' + testObject.id);
      var TestObject2 = Parse.Object.extend("TestObject2");
      var testObject2 = new TestObject2();
      testObject2.set("Name", "testName2");
      testObject2.save(null, {
        success: function(testObject2) {
          // Execute any logic that should take place after the object is saved.
          console.log('New testObject2 created with objectId: ' + testObject2.id);
          var relation = testObject.relation("TestObjectRelation");
          console.log('Make sure the relation exists ' + testObject.relation("TestObjectRelation"));

          relation.add(testObject2);
          testObject.save();
        },
        error: function(testObject2, error) {
          // Execute any logic that should take place if the save fails.
          // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
          console.log('Failed to create new testObject2, with error code: ' + error.message);
        }
      });

    },
    error: function(venue, error) {
      // Execute any logic that should take place if the save fails.
      // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
      console.log('Failed to create new testObject, with error code: ' + error.message);
    }
  });
```

Comment: I'd expect to see this if `myreferenceobject` doesn't have a column called "Objects"

Comment: Not the case, It does indeed have the column, I have searched and seen people complain about a similar in in the python sdk ... the column is def there

Comment: could you post the whole history of myObject, myreferenceobject and artist?  how is each created?   I'm particularly interested in built but not yet saved objects.

Comment: @danh ... you asked for it, I posted the code but i realize it's super confusing I tried to also descripbe the logic

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that the failure isn't related to the posted code.

If `testObject` and `testObject2` are valid, and if `testObject` has a column called `TestObjectRelation`, and that column is set up as a relation to `TestObject2` class, then the OP code should work.   But if any of those conditions aren't met, it will fail.

A subjective problem with the code is that it is confusingly named and structured, so it's difficult to judge by reading it whether the conditions hold and whether it does the right thing.

I can't help with the naming unless I understand the domain, but at least we can make the code structure understandable.  Writing it this way will either solve the problem or allow you to discover its origin...

```
function createTestObjectNamed(name) {
    var TestObject = Parse.Object.extend("TestObject");
    var testObject = new TestObject();
    testObject.set("Name", name);
    return testObject.save();
}

function createTestObject2Named(name) {
    var TestObject2 = Parse.Object.extend("TestObject2");
    var testObject2 = new TestObject2();
    testObject2.set("Name", name);
    return testObject2.save();
}

function relateTestObjects(testObject, testObject2) {
   var relation = testObject.relation("TestObjectRelation");
   relation.add(testObject2);
   return testObject.save();
}

function createAndRelateTestObjects() {
    var testObject;
    return createTestObjectNamed("MyName").then(function(result) {
        testObject = result;
        return createTestObject2Named("MyName2");
    }).then(function(testObject2) {
        return relateTestObjects(testObject, testObject2);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error and what worked was upgrading the parse library to 1.6.4

"Resolved in 1.6.4"
https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-JS/issues/4